# sort the content based on click count

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm using [Link Click Count](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_click_count) module.I want to sort the view content based count.how to list sort the content based on link click count.now It displayed the node 4 times if the count is 4.

Comment: add link node id in sort criteria

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure the link click count module
2. Add new field in content type and set 'count the click happened on the link' in manage display
3. Use the default link click count stats view
4. In sort criteria, add the link node id and chooose the you wanted order.

### [image]

5. whenever you click the field in the node, It will be get counted
6. The sorted result based on the click of the link will be shown in the view's result

[image]

Comment: Use the default link click count stats view.how to do this

Comment: Check in Structure/view, it will be in disable mode, enable and use it

Comment: 4 times clicked node displayed 4 times

Comment: In advance setting click 'Query setting' and check distinct to avoid duplicating node